# Multithreaded merge, best java threading practices recommended

Tags: java, multithreading

Problem - Merge 1000 hash-maps into a single map. Assume each hashmap contained alphabets and frequency for 1 page of book, and book had 1000 pages. So we have scanned through each page and created 1000 hashmaps, and now we want to reduce / merge them. This has to be done taking advantage of multithreading. Note - we are not using hadoop as this has to be done on single machine. This question is tailor made to get my doubts solved to please refrain from answers that suggest by-pass to threading.

1. Is this typical problem with known solution ? If yes please point me to any reference links.
2. If not, then how to go about just a reduce-merge problem, given that threads dont return values ? Here is a suggested approach. Work in divide-conquer manner. First spawn 500 threads each combining 2 maps, then spawn 250 threads each combining 2 merged maps ... and so on. Any oppositions ? better ideas  ?

Comment: I am familiar to java jargon and packages linked to threading, thats why i wanted answers in java (preferred)

Comment: What method are you using right now to merge the HashMaps?

Comment: map3 = new HashMap();
map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);

Comment: Well if the number of keys is small and the number of maps is large, spawn a thread for every key and let it sum over all maps writing once at the end in your combined map. No synchronization issues with that. But for summing up a thousand numbers each it is not very efficient to spawn threads. If you have more maps or more complex calculating ns however it might be a good idea.

Comment: @Matthias agree - thats why I mentioned `This question is tailor made to get my doubts solved`

Comment: I'm interested in the performance difference of 8 threads dividing verses 500 threads. I doubt there will be any difference.

Comment: There is no much sence to run more threads that use CPU heavily (your case), than number of cores. So if you have a single machine, you should not run 500 threads for this task there.

Comment: @CodeCamper 2 would probably be faster than 500: less overhead and less contention.

Comment: @Matthias I agree except that there are still synchronization issues on the combined map if it is not thread safe, as it might cache things like the number of entries in nonvolatile variables.  Java does have thread safe map implementations, however - just don't use a vanilla HashMap.

Comment: @warren dew Of course but it is only the inserting into the map which has synch. issues. Either using a synchronized map or gathering the results in a thread safe way would solve this. But keeping the part that needs synch small is usually a good way to have good performance and reduce programming mistakes.

Comment: @Matthias your solution assumes a small fixed alphabet, if that's not true (say the input is the whole Unicode charset) it gets more complicated. You also still need synchronization or static scheduling to figure out which characters each thread should work on.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Java 8 then you could use a parallel stream to get the job done in parallel:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
//populate: one map per page

Map<String, Integer> summary = maps.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (i1, i2) -> i1 + i2));
```

With Java < 8 you would need to parallelisation yourself, for example using the Fork/Join framework (what `parallelStream` does under the hood) or an `ExecutorService`.

In any case, for a CPU intensive task, spawning more threads than the number of processors on your machine will be counterproductive, so unless you run a beast with 500 cores, don't start 500 threads.

---

Complete example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = new ArrayList<>();

  maps.add(map("a cat and a dog and a cat and a dog"));
  maps.add(map("a hat and a man and a man and a cat"));
  maps.add(map("a cat and a dog and a cat and a dog"));
  maps.add(map("a hat and a man and a man and a cat"));
  maps.add(map("a cat and a dog and a cat and a dog"));
  maps.add(map("a hat and a man and a man and a cat"));

  System.out.println(maps);

  Map<String, Integer> summary = maps.parallelStream()
              .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
              //what thread are we on?
              .peek(e -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()))
              .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (i1, i2) -> i1 + i2));

  System.out.println("summary = " + summary);
}
private static Map<String, Integer> map(String text) {
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  for (String s : text.split("\\s+")) {
    Integer count = map.getOrDefault(s, 0) + 1;
    map.put(s, count);
  }
  return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As merge sort is based on divide-and-conqueor strategy, you can do the following:

Merging 1000 HMs could be divided into:

- A: merging first 500;
- B: merging second 500;
- Merging A and B;

Both A and B could be divided into subparts of 250 HMs to merge and so on.

Now when we done with basic idea of parallel merge, lets do some tweaks:

- Starting from some count of HMs, lets say 8, it makes no sense to run merge in parallel - you should do it in a single thread.
- You can use ThreadPoolExecutor to assign merging tasks to a fixed number of threads.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a specific queue for maps to be merged. Start any suitable number of working threads, which do the following:

- poll the queue and take first map. Then all next maps would be merged into this.
- poll the queue and take next map. If the queue is not empty, merge the first map with the next map. If the queue is empty, put the first map (which have grown) back into queue (as an atomic synchronized operation with the poll operation) and exit. Support an integer value reflecting the number of remained threads. If this is the last thread, all work is done and instead of putting back, pass the resulting map to the next processing step.

Full code example see at https://github.com/rfqu/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/reduceMaps/ReduceMaps.java